# Postgres Socket file getting deleted

Tags: postgresql

i was encountering a situation where my Postgres Unix socket File gets deleted . Ideally when our application is running the Postgres deamon should not go down at all . However the postmaster does go down and the unix socket file created at /tmp/ also gets deleted . This has serious implications for our products .

I wanted to know when can the socket file get deleted if one does not do it explicitly . Does it mean the Postgres connection has gone bad and it re-started itself ?  Is that is the case when can the connection go bad ?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear if you mean whether the socket file gets removed because postgresql goes down (which is normal) or whether postgresql goes down because the socket file is removed. Check the postgres logs.

It could be there's a procedure that cleans up old files in /tmp/ . e.g. CentOS/RHEL does this by the means of `tmpwatch` , the /etc/cron.daily/tmpwatch script specifically. And although tmpwatch shouldn't remove the pgsql file, who knows if there's a bug lurking..

Comment: The log file has this : Clearly it was not a graceful shutdown . omeone tried to get it down : I am not sure how or who or why . LOG:  database system was interrupted at 2011-05-06 09:34:19 IST
LOG:  checkpoint record is at 0/96265C0
LOG:  redo record is at 0/96265C0; undo record is at 0/0; shutdown FALSE
LOG:  next transaction ID: 82018; next OID: 787538
LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress

Comment: Also i do realise that the Postgres database is extremely sensitive to the permissions and presence of the /tmp directory . I would ensure that there is no script that deleted the data in tmp

Comment: The log entry you're showing is from recovery when it comes back up.  Look further back in the logs for what killed the database.  It could be something like the OOM killer, in which case look at things like too high work_mem setting.